# How to prevent 'touched' event from firing when user moves finger to slide the element

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, web-applications

**Solution**: https://github.com/alexgibson/tap.js

I have a conflict between 'touchend' and 'touchmove' events on the iPad in mobile Safari. I have images sitting next to each other like a gallery and they have a 'touchend' event attached to flip when touchend. However, you can also slide from one image to the other (like on iPhone sliding home screen to the next screen).

Now I can't figure out how to prevent the 'touchend' event from firing when I want to slide to the next image. Obviously, I don't want the image to flip if I slide, only if I tap.

My solution so far:

```
var img = $('.show-video');

var sliding = false;

img.bind('touchend', function(e) {
    if (sliding === false){
        Animate($(this), 'flip');
    }
});

img.bind('touchmove', function(){
    sliding = true;
    $(this).bind('touchend', function(){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            sliding = false;
        }, 200)
    })
});
```

````

I think this can be done much better.

Comment: Can you block one of those events from bubbling up? For example, does calling `preventDefault()` and `stopPropigation()` on the event object do anything for you?

Comment: Yes but i would need to prevent it from "bubbling" down. I have a "ul" which contains the elements within its "li's" and when i touch the "li" it should do something, but when i slide over the ul with my finger it should just slide to the next page, even if a finger was placed on one of the li's to slide.

I've updated my post with a hacky solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library adds a 'tap' event which you can use to watch for a "tap" instead of "touchend".

https://github.com/alexgibson/tap.js

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two events when it comes to tapping the screen: `touchstart` and `touchend`. When a user touches the screen, the first event is captured, when he stops touching the screen, the second event is fired. The `touchmove` event should be captured to analyse the movement of the finger.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to say, but I'm assuming you you are capturing those events. What you can do is:

1. Instead of doing something on `touchstart` do it on `touchend`. This is more natural anyway, since something should happen after you lift the finger
2. After `touchstart` see if there is any movement using `touchmove`. If none and `touchend` is called, do what you wanted to do for a tap. If there was movement, do whatever you wanted to do for sliding.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am using touchend but how can i "see" if there is any movement and how can i cancel the "touchend" behavior?

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/), it explains everything nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a workaround on this once.

You been already explained what are the events that are happening, and also you have a clue as a question.

For example  lets say you have your gallery on a #galleryOverlay, and you scroller is inside it.

Then all you have to do is something like

$('#galleryOverlay').bind('touchstart  touchmove touchmove', function(e){e.stopPropagation();})

So this way you keep your events inside your gallery, but you prevent them to happen outside.

Good luck

Comment: Yes but the images i want to tap on are in the same gallery.